# Robot Framework: can i set suite from multiple test files without locate in same file?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using `Robot Framework` so I have several test file (`.robot`).
When I run this files with tag `command` or several files in the same `command` each `robot` file is recognized as suite because this are separate files, Is it possible to run `robot` files separate and define this files as belong to specific suite without concatenate this files into one file ?

Comment: no you cant'. A file being a suite is at the root of Robot. But maybe you could explain why this is a problem for you and what you are failing to achieve with this multiple file/suite organization, so that we can help you in another way.

Comment: I want to be able to write each test in asperate file (already have it) and several files that in each directory will be suite (without concatenate to one file)